# Are 'everyone' and 'every one' are interchangeable when I use them to refer to people?

Tags: difference

When I use 'everyone' or 'every one' to refer to people, are they interchangeable? For example, here are some sentences:

> As soon as everyone had arrived, we began the meeting.

> She's very popular. Everyone likes her.

Can I replace 'everyone' in these sentences with 'every one'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Everyone* as a single word means 'all the people who are/were present' or sometimes 'people in general' (as in your second example).

If you write it as two words, or say it with more stress on *one*, is means 'each individual'.

> Every one of my children has a different interest.